# Run each pixel through a rectangular PGraphics (Processing)

Tags: java, arrays, processing, pixel

I have a squared PGraphics where I want to read the color of each pixel. I do this with the following lines:

```
size(1080,1080, P2D);
pg = createGraphics(width, height, P2D);
```

…then in draw:

```
 pg.loadPixels();
  for (int y = 0; y < pixel; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < pixel; x++) {
      int ix = int(size*x);
      int iy = int(size*y);
      color c = pg.pixels[iy * width + ix];
```

However, if I now change the size so that the PGrpahics or my sketch window is no longer squared I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error message. I know that you can also read the pixels from rectangular sketches, for example with:

```
   pixels[x+y*width] = …etc
```

Works fine – but what is it that I am missing above if I change the size to lets say `size(1920,1080, P2D);`?

Comment: pixels[x+y*width] = …etc Should work I think , but maybe you have the same upper boundary for the two for loops like in the example above instead of the outer loop be bounded by number of rows and the inner loop be bounded by number of columns ?

Comment: Ah yes! This is it! I have less rows than columns! thank you!